# Swift auto generated modulemap on framework

Tags: swift, xcode, module, frameworks

I have a custom framework that uses some modules in manuel created `module.modulemap`:-

```
module SQLite [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
    export *
}

module zlib [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h"
    export *
}
```

When I build my framework, new `module.modulemap` file generates automatically like this:-

```
  framework module MyFramework{
  umbrella header "MyFramework.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}

module MyFramework.Swift {
    header "MyFramework-Swift.h"
}
```

And when I import my framework to new project, I get missing required modules "sqlite","zlib" error.
I tried to edit auto generated modulemap file with texteditor like this;

```
framework module MyFramework{
  umbrella header "MyFramework.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}

module MyFramework.Swift {
    header "MyFramework-Swift.h"
}

module SQLite [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
    export *
}

module zlib [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h"
    export *
}
```

And it works.

How can I import my modules to auto generated modulemap automatically? Or How can I fix "missing required modules "sqlite","zlib"" error?
Thanks for helps.